# How to apply active class for first list item using mootools

Tags: mootools

```
<div class="accordion">
<ul class="navigation">
    <li>Lorem</li>
    <li>Ipsum</li>
    <li>Donor</li>
</ul>
<ul class="navigation">
    <li>Test</li>
    <li>Demo</li>
    <li>Donor</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

How can we apply a class which is 'active' to first 'li' (ie;Lorem) only, not for all first 'li' under 'ul' using mootools.
I would like to get output as

```
<div class="accordion">
<ul class="navigation">
    <li class="active">Lorem</li>
    <li>Ipsum</li>
    <li>Donor</li>
</ul>
<ul class="navigation">
    <li>Test</li>
    <li>Demo</li>
    <li>Donor</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`document.getElement("ul.navigation > li").addClass("active");` will work.

so will

`document.getElement("ul.navigation").getFirst("li").addClass("active");`